# EXPRESS - Can't send "+" sign in POST

Tags: ajax

Simple question. I am sending POST request through AJAX:

```
`myreq=${JSON.stringify({info: "+"})}`
```

But all what I get in req.body.myreq is:

```
{"info":" "}
```

It's empty string or space... How I can send "+" sign??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) form of `+` is `%2B`. If you're using Javascript, perhaps use the [encodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) function on your string, to encode it before sending it in a request. Remember that you'll need to use [decodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) (or whatever language-specific equivalent) to decode it on the response side of the request, so that you can use it again.